# Rest endpoint to get pod whose name starts with a certain string

Tags: openshift, redhat, kubernetes-helm

openshift document says we can use the below to get pod by name:

```
curl -k \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    https://$ENDPOINT/api/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/pods/$NAME
```

I want to get a pod that starts with a certain string with a * wild card in the end.

Example:

```
curl -k \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    https://$ENDPOINT/api/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/pods/mypod*
```

but this does not work.

how do i achieve what i needed?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your should use list api [get all Pods in a namespace](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/rest_api/api/v1.Pod.html#Get-api-v1-namespaces-namespace-pods)
2. Selection by [fields](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/) and [labels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) are limited. Only equality or set-based operations for label selectors; and =, ==, != operators for field selectors.
3. Of cause it depends on use cases of rest api but in bash environment you have *jq* to match objects:

   ```
   curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H 'Accept: application/json' https://master.lab1.example.com:8443/api/v1/namespaces/test/pods | jq '.items[] | select(.metadata.name | match("^test"))'
   ```